# C# .NET Visual Studio: different executables for WinForms project?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I would like to run executable files of my WinForms application on other Windows machines.

However Visual Studio seems to build multiple executables for the same project in my workspace.

There is one executable in `Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AmazonImport\AmazonImport\bin\Debug` and another one in `Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AmazonImport\AmazonImport\obj\Debug`

I have heard some people using executables stored in their `ProjectName\ProjectName\bin\Release` folder but my `Release` folder is empty.

What is the difference between these executable files? is one compiled with debugger flags and the other isn't?

Both executables work fine and they are the same size, what is the difference?

What is the proper way of distributing my application?

Comment: Set your project in RELEASE mode, compile it and take the executable in the BIN\RELEASE folder

Comment: And ignore the `obj` directory - it's effectively just intermediate files.

Comment: perhaps you should read the following [MSDN Walkthrough: Deploying a Windows based Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3bb4tfd(v=vs.80).aspx)